# Uncertainty about inputs

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I'm executing an external program via python and if the external program asks for input then my python script must prompt me for input and continue with execution again with those inputs..

**Is there any way to find if stdin for a process is active to accept input?**

Comment: It reminds me of the halting problem. I don't think what you are trying to is possible

Comment: say.,. I'm executing an external pgm via python and if the external program asks for input then my python script must prompt me for input and continue with execution again with those inputs

Comment: How are you currently running the external program? subprocess? `system`?

Comment: @kevin subprocess.peopen

Comment: Could you explain your requirement a little better?

Comment: Everytime if an external pgm (executed thru python with subprocess.peopen) is asking for input, my python script would prompt and get those input from me and provide it as input for that external pgm?

Comment: What kind of prompt? Is it a password propmt?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "random inputs"?

Comment: no just plain texts.. and random means we cannot expect how many inputs or when we would get prompt for inputs. which would prevent us from using "pexpect" feature of python

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20408/discussion-between-everlasto-and-keith)

Comment: I see. Well yes I could do that with my own expect module. So yes, there is a way. Unfortunately I don't think it can be shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pexpect module:
http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect

It allows you to run a process and wait for certain patterns, and then send input and read results. You would need to know what you are expecting and maybe wait for certain timeouts until you get the input prompt.

It would be a lot more complicated if your program is completely random in when it will prompt.

Comment: Ya actually I cant use pexpect with my pgm due to random inputs.. so I posted question here..

Comment: Is the pattern of the input prompts known? And just the time they show up random?

Comment: Patterns arent known.. I'm trying to make an user to type a c program in my script and run it there itself.. Can u get me?

Comment: But that sounds like you are waiting on input from the very start. Unless you are allowing them to submit a program and runs and does any kind of input at any time. You would have to alternate between reading stdin with a timeout and reading stdout with a timeout

Answer (score 0):

**Assume if console is idle for 10 seconds, it might wait for input**,

Note: Not always this case, say if thread is sleeping etc..,

But for simplicity, I assumed former.

So,

```
process=subprocess.Popen(['some_process_with_inputs'],shell=true,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)  
start = time.time()  
time_to_wait_for_idleness=10  
while 1:  
    ret=process.poll()  
    if ret == None and (time.time() - start) > time_to_wait_for_idleness:  
        #Waiting for input possibly.. Do things here ie.. process.communicate() 
    time.sleep(1)
```

Just a suggestion, might help someone. Thanks for responses.